# Javascript what is the difference between var = null, and var = {}

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how to check against an empty variable, here is a code snippet:

```
    var test = {};

    if (test === null){
        console.log("TRUE!");
    }        
    else{
        console.log("False :(");
    }
    if (test === undefined){
        console.log("TRUE!");
    }
    else{
        console.log("False :(");
    }
```

Result is False for both conditions, how can I compare against an non-initialized/empty variable?

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(test).length`. Note that `test` in your code is not empty, it contains a reference to an empty object.